# For WPF TreeView, how can I use a theme while also setting the TreeView.ItemContainerStyle

Tags: wpf, treeview, treeviewitem

I use this in XAML to load the treeview children from a view model based on Josh Smith's sample code [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithViewModel.aspx):

```
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </Style>
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

This causes the theme I'm using for TreeViewItem to be ignored. It makes the selected item text black and the background darkblue so it's hard to read. Is there a way to use both the theme and the code above at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting [`BasedOn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon.aspx) to `{StaticResource {x:Type TreeViewItem}}`.

This will take the default style for `TreeViewItems` (which is provided by the theme) as the base for your style.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not sure where to put that. I tried it here, but it says TreeViewItem not found.    'code'<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle> <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TreeViewItem}}"> <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" /> <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" /> </Style> </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>'code'

Comment: Actually, that worked any way despite the error. Thanks for your help.

Comment: That code looks fine to me... Edit: Oh yeah, just ignore the errors.

Comment: It won't let me upvote your answer because I need more reputation, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Just the code formated:

```
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle> 
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:TypeTreeViewItem}"> 
        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" /> 
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" /> 
    </Style> 
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```